# Automate CocoaPods installation with the right version

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I start working on an existing project and it uses Cocoapods as a dependency manager and this is my first time using it. After installation, I ran `pod init` and then add dependencies one by one by hand and used `pod install` to install them.

Now I have a problem with dependencies versions and I cannot change the project version. Is there a way that I can find out the project's dependencies' versions? and is there a way so I can automate CocoaPods installation so I don't need to write them one by one?

There is no Pod file and also pod.framework files are red and transparent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The client has forgotten to push the Podfile to the repository. I asked for the Podfile. After putting the file in my project directory I was able to build the app after running `pod install` in my terminal. For beginners, I suggest not putting Podfile in your .gitignore file.

Answer (score 1):

In your frameworks repo, see which versions are compatible with your version that you are working with. And then, in your `Podfile` implement the frameworks like this:

```
pod 'AFNetworking', '1.2.0'
```

Check 'Get started' at http://cocoapods.org

If you are using an older version of swift, it could be that the Framework you are using, uses the latest version of swift and that is why it is not working.

A tip for not installing one by one:

```
pod instal               // will install all dependencies 
pod instal --repo-update // will install only the ones that needs to update
pod update               // will install and update everything
```

Comment: pod framework files are red and I can't open them. What is the problem?

Comment: this es expected for some versions of Xcode, the Xcode doesn't understand them, but it is not a problem. inside de pods project, only worry with the `Podfile`

Comment: the code if you want to check it out, is inside the pods project. but not in the same folder as the .framework files. I'm sure you can find them